# C program crashes by calling realloc() several times

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, realloc

I have been working on and off on an assignment for my C class for the last few days and encountered a curious crash concerning the realloc() function in C. Even the C/C++ programmers in house could not answer me right away what might be wrong with my code.

First i create the memory block in one function:

```
char *line = (char *)malloc( sizeof(char) * BUFSIZE);
```

Then i call `getMoreBuf(start_of_block, end_of_block)`

```
int getMoreBuf(char *start, char *end)
{
char *newBuf = 0;
int newSize = (end - start) + BUFSIZE;
    newBuf = (char *)realloc(start, sizeof(char) * newSize);
    if(NULL == newBuf) {
        printf("No virtual RAM available");
    }else{
        start = newBuf;
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Depending on what i set the BUFSIZE to, it crashes after the 5th call (BUFSIZE = 1) or the 3rd call (BUFSIZE = 5) and replaces the read in characters with nonsense.

Could someone point me towards my error(s) and give suggestions where to read up on to fix them?
Any help is appreciated. :)

**Bonus Question:** I malloc a memory block with pointer 1 pointing to the start and later pointer 2 point2 towards a single block in the memory block. I realloc() the block and the block is moved due to size issues, does the pointer 2 still point to the old (now useless) block or does it "move" with the realloc to the new position of the memory block?

(Also for the future,  should i put that extra question into a new question or can i leave it in here since it is strongly related to the first question?)

**Thank you all for your input, it helped me a great deal to figure out what went wrong.
If i could i would mark each as the right answer since each helped my in some form to understand a bit more about all this damn pointer business. =)**

Comment: [*Even the programmers*](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) Maybe you should have tried C programmers ?

Comment: Yes, i tried a C and a C++ programmer, i just forgot to mention that. I fixed that and i will look into the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're only changing the local variable `start`... You need to use a pointer.

```
int getMoreBuf(char **start, char **end)
{
    char *newBuf = 0;
    int newSize = (*end - *start) + BUFSIZE;
    newBuf = (char *)realloc(*start, sizeof(char) * newSize);
    if(NULL == newBuf) {
        printf("No virtual RAM available");
    } else {
        *start = newBuf;
        *end = *start + newSize;
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

And then you'd call it like:

```
getMoreBuf(&start_of_block, &end_of_block)
```

Comment: Note that `end` probably needs to get recomputed, too -- otherwise the computation for `newSize` will deliver the wrong value...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had hoped for a bit of input to figure it out on my own but this works too. I hope i can keep this all in mind for next time. :)

Comment: `*start + newSize;` doesn't work, i need to substract `BUFSIZE` from it before it does. And i need to think about it for some more time for figure out a neater and comprehensible wy to do that. So exactly what i need, more food for thought!

Comment: @Plastefuchs: You sure you need to subtract `BUFSIZE` and not `1`?

Comment: @Plastefuchs: By the way, regarding your bonus question: The pointer doesn't change, it is left dangling to bad memory.

Comment: @cha0site: If i substract one i am still only (BUFSIZE - 1) behind the last pointer. I tried several versions and stared at the momory in VS and this corrections was the one that made it work the way i need it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
start = newBuf;
```

is modifying `start`.  But `start` is a local variable; it won't affect the variable that the caller has.

To solve this, you either need to take `start` as pointer-to-pointer, or you need to return `newBuf`.

Comment: @Plastefuchs: No, it will not.  You need to modify the pointer itself, so you need to pass a pointer to it, i.e. a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me to overthink a few things i thought i already knew about pointers and functions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the new value of `start` is not being passed out of the `getMoreBuf()` function -- you would need a double pointer to do this, i.e. your function prototype would need to look like this:

```
int getMoreBuf(char **start, char **end);
```

(I've made `end` a double pointer too since you will likely need to compute a new value for it, too.)